# Bloomberg Data in Python using TIA

Tags: python

I am new to Python world but very experienced with MATLAB. After doing some research, I found out that TIA is a versatile way to download Bloomberg data in Python.

So, I wrote the code below

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
import pandas as pd
sec= ['HEDJ US Equity', 'EFA US Equity']
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data(sec, ['PX_LAST', 'PX_OPEN'])
resp.as_frame()
```

Problem is - I think this function is sorting Sec alphabetically. Thus I see results like.

```
                PX_LAST  PX_OPEN
EFA US EQUITY     69.07    68.85
HEDJ US Equity    65.22    64.89
```

Eevn though HEDJ came before in my list. This leads me to two questions -

A. How to is suppress sorting of SEC in this case
B. Generally, if i have to look for Optional Arguments for a given inbuilt function in Python, how do I do that?

Thanking python pr community.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sorting per se but they are not requested in the order of your list.
but to get back the frame in your order all you need to do is:

```
resp.as_frame().loc[sec]
```